# How to store fa-icons value in checkbox

Tags: database, codeigniter-2

How to store fa-icons values in checkbox in MySQL using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="/action_page.php">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="fa-icon" name="icon" value="cat">

  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">submitt</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In this example, we've got a name of icon, and a value of cat. When the form is submitted, the data name/value pair will be icon=cat.

If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on , so the submitted data in that case would be animal=on.

`<i class="icon-<?= $this->input->post('icon'); ?>"></i> <img src="cat-<?= $this->input->post('icon'); ?>.jpg"  height="42" width="42">` 
will give you "cat -image or cat-icon"

Comment: thanks for reply my question 
Stefan Avramovic. if i get the values it should came like cat icon?

Comment: echo  $this->input->post('icon');  will output "cat"

Comment: stefan am not asking about the value "cat" am asking about while we geetting the  echo $this->input->post('icon'); will output "cat -image or cat-icon"

Comment: <i class="icon-<?=  $this->input->post('icon'); ?>"></i>   <img src="cat-<?=  $this->input->post('icon'); ?>.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> will give you  "cat -image or cat-icon"

Comment: ya i will try stefan  thank you so much i think result should came using this method

Answer (score 0):

By using name attribute
The name attribute specifies the name of an  element. The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted. Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Comment: please explain clearly with codeignator (PHP framework) yar Mr.Fahad

Comment: sorry just have experience in core :(

Comment: my pleasure always